# Difference between either and ether

Tags: sounds

Even though they mean completely different things why do either and ether sound so similar to eachother?

Comment: Is it just the English language being overly complicated or is there another reason why either and ether sound so similar?

Comment: I don't think this is complicated, I've never seen the two words confused with each other. There are lots of English words that sounds alike.

Comment: I have never considered them to be similar. The "th" sound is different. There are many other word pair hononyms, such as **their** and **there** which really are often confused.

Comment: Yeah that's true I was just interested if there was any reason they sound so alike but maybe there isn't thanks though

Comment: That's a good point weather vane I didn't think if that yes one "th" is a harder "th" sound then the other

Comment: There are two ways that "either" is pronounced. I say "eye-ther" but I have never thought anyone else was saying "ether".

Comment: Yes well I had it conflated with that word ether which turns out means a gas substance  and nothing at all to do with either but I guess I answered my own question anyway, thanks though

Comment: @nnnnnn There are lots of them, like "I couldn't bear to see the bear approching across the bare ground so I sped to the shed where I house my garden hose".

Comment: These two words don't sound exactly alike though.

Comment: [Let's call the whole thing off!](https://youtu.be/LOILZ_D3aRg)

Answer (score 4):

Modern English has two phonemes that developed out of one in Middle English and never quite split completely. Therefore it comes as a surprise to most literate Modern English speakers when they find out that there are two different phonemes, pronounced differently in English, but both spelled `TH`.

One is voiced in Modern English, like *the, this, other, either, mother, father,* and *fathom,* and represented in the IPA  by the letter "edh" (**ð**), which occurred in Old and Middle English texts, along with another character "thorn" (**þ**) that was used instead. These letters were in free variation, like different versions of handwritten letters today are. (In Old and Middle English, of course, **all** letters were handwritten.) Both of these letters still occur in Modern Icelandic, which is very archaic.

This voiced phoneme appears in all the Germanic words that occur in the grammar, and is therefore very common, because words like *the, this, that, these, those, them, their, there,* etc. occur so very frequently in English speech. Most of the words with /ð/ either don't have a meaning (like *the*), or have a meaning that's very difficult to state without giving examples, like *other* or *either*. Looking up these words in a dictionary is unsatisfying; they're part of the grammar, not the lexicon.

The other phoneme spelled `TH` in Modern English is voiceless, as in *theater, thistle, ether, ethylene, moth, myth, sheath,* and *thicken*. It's represented in IPA by the letter "theta" (**θ**), from the Greek alphabet, where it's pronounced the same way. Words with this sound tend to be borrowed from other languages (often Greek), and they have meanings and can be looked up in dictionaries with success.

This pair of English phonemes /ð/ and /θ/ developed when Modern English began to distinguish voiced fricatives (/v ð z ʒ/) from voiceless (/f θ s ʃ h/), maybe around 1300 in some dialects, later in others. There was a common rule of voicing that we still find in some words with irregular morphology, like

- *leaf* (sg) /lif/ versus *leaves* (pl) /livz/ [plural gets voiced final stem]
- *sheath* (n) /ʃiθ/ versus *sheathe* (v) /ʃið/ [verbalization voices final stem]
- *breath* (n) /brɛθ/ versus *breathe* (v) /brið/ [verbalization lengthens stem vowel and voices final]
- *house* (n) /haws/ versus *house* (v) /hawz/ [verbalization voices final stem]

But these have faded into minor irregularities as the voicing of fricatives became widespread in Modern English. And because the dental fricatives are so split into word categories, there are very very few minimal pairs for /ð/ and /θ/ and they are easy to ignore if you're not told anything about pronunciation. And native speakers educated in Anglophone school systems are not taught anything about English pronunciation, only about its spelling. So it's easy to miss something like this.

Linguists say that the contrast between these two phonemes has a low functional yield. That means you don't need to distinguish them very often. The only minimal pairs I know, none of them very good, are

- *This'll* and *thistle* , which is comparing a noun to a contracted phrase
- *either* and *ether*, which refers to only one pronunciation of *either*
- *thy* and *thigh*, which compares a modern word to an archaic one

That's why you didn't notice before, and that's why we can still get away with spelling them both the same.

Comment: I am unclear on your last point, regarding _this'll_ and _thistle_, etc. One is /ð/, the other /θ/. Are you saying they sound similar, or have the same difference as either/ether?

Comment: Also, I was confused initially by which pronunciation of _either_ was being discussed: /ˈʌɪðə/ or /ˈiːðə/

Comment: @marcellothearcane:  (a) _This'll_ contrasts with _thistle_, but _This'll_ is not a word; it's a contraction of two words. That's not a proper minimal pair. (b) I'm considering only the /iðəɹ/ pronunciation (American phonemics). The /ayðəɹ/ pronunciation isn't a minimal pair, either.

Answer (score 0):

The '*th*' is pronounced differently for each word

Either has a '*th*' sounds like the word '***th***en'

Ether has a '*th*' sounds like the word '***th***ought'

Try sounding the '*th*' from each word and saying 'eee-then' and 'eee-thought' and you might see the difference.

I also found [this link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xCP7DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=either%20ether%20sound%20difference&source=bl&ots=_PvDZxGhrD&sig=ACfU3U3TAQhL6gZGVZE3e-k3uMcN4-FpZw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiq7uaQgeTjAhVsQxUIHS1XBRYQ6AEwBHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=either%20ether%20sound%20difference&f=false) that helped confirm there are two ways to sound '*th*'

Worth noting (as in comments) there are two forms of pronunciation for *either* (eee-thuh and eye-thuh) and it's only the *eee* form that is close to the same pronunciation as *ether*